# How to get Beyond Compare exe full path using python?

Tags: python, exe

I am trying to find full path of Beyond Compare exe with following code. But both giving output as `None.`

```
from shutil import which
print(which('BCompare'))

from distutils import spawn
print(spawn.find_executable('BCompare'))
```

Expected ouput:

```
C:\Program Files\Beyond Compare 4\BCompare.exe
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Naive question, but have you tried `'BCompare.exe'`?

Comment: @mozway that shouldn't be required. More likely, OP's problem is that `BCompare.exe` is not on the path for the environment that runs their Python script.

Comment: @mozway I tried. It is giving None output

Comment: @Grismar thus the *naive question*, I'm not familiar with windows ;)

Comment: @AshokAnumula have you checked that bcompare is on the path for the environment from which you run Python?

Comment: @Grismar My python environment is in `C:\Users\anumua2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39` and my beyond compare is in `C:\Program Files\Beyond Compare 4\BCompare.exe`.

Comment: @Grismar For notepad script is working fine; which is in the path `C:\WINDOWS\system32\notepad.EXE`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your Beyond Compare is installed in `C:\Program Files\Beyond Compare 4`, try this:

```
from os import environ
from pathlib import Path

location = r'C:\Program Files\Beyond Compare 4'
dirs_on_path = [dir.strip('\\') for dir in environ['path'].split(';')]

if location in dirs_on_path:
    print('directory is on the path')
    if (Path(location) / 'BCompare.exe').is_file():
        print('and executable could be found, which("BCompare") should work')
    else:
        print('but executable could not be found')
else:
   print('directory is not on the path')
```

Either your program location is not on the path (a system environment variable, more on how to change it here - just the top result I picked from Google https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/)

Or the location is on the path, but the executable is not there. The script tests both and lets you know - that should allow you to figure out the problem.

Comment: I added program location `C:\Program Files\Beyond Compare 4` in the environment variable path. But above code is giving output `directory is not on the path` instead of `and executable could be found, which("BCompare") should work`. But `which(BCompare')` is giving correct output now `C:\Program Files\Beyond Compare 4`